# How to flip pictures/video with Camera2 API

Tags: android, xamarin, android-camera2

My camera sensor is looking through a prism, so I am trying to mirror pictures and video that are captured with the Android Camera2 API. I am able to flip and manipulate the TextureView which fixes the live view, but that doesn't affect the captured media. To flip the TextureView I call:

```
matrix.PostScale(-1, 1, centerX, centerY);
textureView.SetTransform(matrix);
```

Does anyone have any ideas on an alternative approach?

Answer (score -1):

Are you storing the live view in a Bitmap? If so, you can do:

```
Bitmap bmp; // Your bitmap
Bitmap newBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```